# Swift - Characters in text field are not visible

Tags: swift, uitextfield, ios11

In my application I have several custom designed games to practice spelling and grammar. The whole process was working just fine until iOS 11 released.

**An overview of how my application works:**

- the game receives a random word and picture from our server and automatically creates a stack of text fields (in a horizontal stack view)
- the amount of text fields is similar to the amount of letters of the received word (e.g. the word "throw" would create five text fields next to each other)
- the view is linked to a custom keyboard that is displayed until all questions are answered correctly
- the text fields reset themselves if the user's input is not similar to the expected answer

**The problem since iOS 11**

Only the first two questions don't show the user's input in their respective text fields (the first letter always seem to work). The console also confirms that the input and the comparison of the letters does indeed work, but the text fields stay empty all the time. The game even resets perfectly and goes to the next question if the word has been answered correctly. **The weird thing is that question 3, 4 and 5 do not have this problem.**

In the example below you can see what is going on. The first question ("plant") only shows the first letter. The second question ("clap") does the same thing. The third question ("bite") does not have this problem. My custom cursor works just fine and automatically jumps to the next box.

[image: The first three questions]

**Swift Code (functionality only)**

```
let TEXT_FIELD_TAG = 1000
let CURSOR_INDEX = 0

var game: GameDictionary? {
    didSet {

        self.m_Client.GetMediaImage(game?.Image) { (image) in
            self.imageView.image = image
        }

        self.selectedIndex = 0
        self.answerChars = (game?.Content?.map { String($0).lowercased() })!
        self.views = (0..<self.answerChars.count).map { _ in UITextField() }

        var index: NSInteger = TEXT_FIELD_TAG

        for textField in self.views {
            textField.backgroundColor = .white
            textField.textColor = Constants.MAIN_THEME_COLOR
            textField.font = UIFont(name: Constants.GAME_FONT_TYPE_1, size: scaledFontSize(fontSize: 36))
            textField.textAlignment = .center
            textField.delegate = self
            textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
            textField.tag = index
            textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            // Create the cursor object and animate the blinking
            let cursor = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: scaledViewSize(viewSize: 10), y: scaledViewSize(viewSize: 10), width: 2, height: scaledViewSize(viewSize: 30)))
            cursor.backgroundColor = Constants.MAIN_THEME_COLOR
            cursor.isHidden = true

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {() -> Void in
                cursor.alpha = 0
            }, completion: {(_ animated: Bool) -> Void in
                cursor.alpha = 1
                }
            )

            textField.addSubview(cursor)
            self.container.addArrangedSubview(textField)

            index+=1
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Question handlers
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    inputArray.removeAll()
    answerChars.removeAll()

    self.selectedIndex = 0

    for view in self.views {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    self.views.removeAll()
}

override func onFocus() {
    self.resetCursorTextField()

    keyboardLauncher.onKeyPressed = { character in
        self.views[self.selectedIndex].text = character
        self.textChanged(sender: self.views[self.selectedIndex])
    }

    keyboardLauncher.showKeyboard()
    keyboardLauncher.enableKeyboard()
}

func resetCursorTextField() {
    for (index, textfield) in self.views.enumerated() {
        textfield.subviews[CURSOR_INDEX].isHidden = (index == 0) ? false : true
    }
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.count + string.count - range.length
    return newLength <= 1
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func resetInputViews() {
    inputArray.removeAll()

    self.selectedIndex = 0
    self.resetCursorTextField()

    for tag in TEXT_FIELD_TAG...(TEXT_FIELD_TAG + (self.answerChars.count) - 1) {
        let textField = self.container.viewWithTag(tag) as! UITextField!
        textField?.text = ""

        if (tag == TEXT_FIELD_TAG) {
            textField?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}

func textChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    if (sender.text?.count)! > 0 {
        inputArray.append((sender.text?.lowercased())!)

        if self.answerChars[self.selectedIndex] != inputArray.last! {
            self.delegate?.updateAnswer(inputArray.joined(), false)
            self.resetInputViews()

        } else {
            self.selectedIndex+=1

            let nextField = sender.superview?.viewWithTag(sender.tag + 1) as! UITextField!
            nextField?.becomeFirstResponder()

            sender.subviews[CURSOR_INDEX].isHidden = true
            nextField?.subviews[CURSOR_INDEX].isHidden = false

            if self.answerChars.count == inputArray.count {
                playCorrectAnswer()
                isCompleted = true

                keyboardLauncher.disableKeyboard()

                self.textField?.isEnabled = false
                self.delegate?.updateAnswer(inputArray.joined(), true)
                self.delegate?.nextQuestion(self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CellForItemAtIndexpath**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item == self.m_Collection?.count {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: gameScoreOverviewCell, for: indexPath) as! GameScoreOverviewCell
        cell.closeViewButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeView(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.rulesButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAlertScoreOverview(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    let game = self.m_Collection![indexPath.item]

    if game.StarryGrade == StarryGrade.Grade4 && game.Level == Level.Level1 {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: fourthGradeCellLevel1, for: indexPath) as! GameCellFourthGradeLevel1
        cell.cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeViewWithAlert(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.questionLabel.text = "Question \(indexPath.item + 1) of \(self.m_Collection!.count)"
        cell.game = game
        cell.delegate = self

        keyBoardIsVisible = true

        return cell  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is it relevant that `override func onFocus` is missing the `super.onFocus()` ?

Comment: I have tried, but it still doesn't work. It works in iOS 10 though. And it also works for question 3 and beyond!

Comment: may you try to comment these ?: `sender.subviews[CURSOR_INDEX].isHidden = true` and 
`nextField?.subviews[CURSOR_INDEX].isHidden = false`. See what happens

Comment: Still the same problem, and this also deactivates my cursor when I go the next question.

Comment: what happens if inside `shouldChangeCharactersIn` you force `return true` (please comment also the `guard`)

Comment: Same outcome. The game continues to the next question if answered correctly, but only the first two questions do not work properly (empty fields). Why would it suddenly work for question 3, 4 and 5. I use a collection view with five cells that automatically swipe horizontally.

Comment: might you post the code inside of `func cellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath)` ?

Comment: Sorry for the somewhat late reply. I have added the cell code to my post. I have different grades and levels, so the above is the one specifically for this type of game (with the text fields).

Comment: why `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is false ?

Comment: Because the keyboard you see is not Apple's keyboard, so I have to force the original one to stay hidden. I use my own custom made keyboard to give the player only access to characters I want them to use.

Comment: Can you share how you presented this view? Are you adding question view on scrollview or something like that?

Comment: I use a UIViewController with an embedded UICollectionView. Every screen is a UICollectionViewCell that scrolls to the next question if answered correctly. It only happens in iOS 11, so Apple must have changed something.

Comment: May you give us more info about this: "the keyboard you see is not Apple's keyboard, so I have to force the original one to stay hidden". ?

Comment: I made my own keyboard (the one you see) and present it when the user starts a game. Focusing on a text field in Swift normally launches Apple’s keyboard, but I don’t want to use the official one (reason: too many unnecessary characters and buttons). I send the user’s input to the text field and jump to the next one if correct. The input works just fine (console confirms that). Furthermore, question 3, 4, and 5 work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a programmatic issue, but an interface issue. Try the following:

1. Ensure that you are compiling the app for Debug
2. Recreate the scenario in the left image below, where you have typed some letters and they are hidden:
   [image]
3. Click this button in the Debug Navigator:

[image]

4. Select *View UI Hierarchy*.
5. In the deconstruction of your UI in Xcode, click on a text field that contains a hidden character.
6. You should now check a few things:

   - in the Object Inspector in the right panel, check to make sure that the Text Field's `Title` attribute is the character you typed (if not, the Text Field isn't capturing the keyboard input)
   - also in the Object Inspector, make sure that the View `Visibility` attribute is set to *Not Hidden*
   - in the Size Inspector (also in the right panel), check to make sure that the Text Field is big enough to show the character

I've had a similar issue before, and these steps allowed me to determine the cause of the problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: The character input works just fine and it is not set to hidden. All the characters fit perfectly as well. Thanks for the detailed answer, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @DennisvanMazijk You can also try clicking the _Show Clipped Content_ button, then drag your mouse to check behind the Text Field.

Comment: What could be the cause that only the first two questions have this problem? There is nothing in my code or views that do something different for question 3, 4 and 5. I really want this bug to go away :-(

Comment: @DennisvanMazijk I don't know. I think it's important to pinpoint what's different about the broken Text Fields in order to then figure out how to fix them.